# Some numbers in notation, what does it mean and how do I replicate it in Guitar Pro?

Tags: sheet-music, classical-music, guitar-pro

I am trying to copy a page of (guitar) music notation to Guitar Pro, but I am a bit confused about what the numbers above ( "4" "3" "2" "3") and numbers in circles ("3" "2") mean... as well as how do I get that to dispaly in Guitar Pro as well so its a 'proper' copy.

Attached is the image (below this text) so you can see what I am talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer :

The circled numbers are the string numbers and the uncircled numbers are the finger numbers.

For example, the first chord annotation asks you to play the F-sharp by placing your 4'th finger (at the 7'th fret) of the 2'nd string (i.e., the B string), and to play the D-natural by placing your 3'rd finger (at the 7'th fret) of the 3'rd string (i.e., the G string).

And the same rules apply to the second chord.

Sorry I can't help you with Guitar Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Jacob obviously does not use Guitar Pro 6 ... It is a really wonderful piece of software... but their manual is absolutely horrible. While the advice to "rtfm" is well taken, in this case it won't do much good.

But I digress. I wanted to share the somewhat convoluted method I have for inserting "numbers in circles" (guitar string numbers) into my scores. (I too have found no dedicated method in GP6 for doing this.)

A little disclaimer here. The method I use can only insert one single "circled number" into a score at a time. They cannot be "stacked" as in Ryans' example. So this solution will only work for a single note at a time.

My method requires two steps:

Step 1: Find a source to pick up the symbol I want... let's say ⑥ (six)

Step 2: Insert that symbol as "lyrics" into GP6.

For my "source" I simply used "Word Perfect 2013". In a new document, I clicked on the "Insert" menu icon, the used "Insert symbol" or "insert number" (far right side of menu) to find the circled number I wanted. Once I have it in WP2013, I can just highlight the character and copy it into the computer buffer (Control-C).

Then I go to GP6, click the little "Lyrics" microphone Icon (bottom on on left control-panel). and insert it (Control-V) there.

Granted there is a short learning curve on inserting lyrics into GP6... but it's not too bad. Mainly it's just figuring out how to space things to get the symbol where you want it.

I found this little YouTube video (produced by GP6 people) that gives the basics of inserting lyrics (in this case a "lyric" is a circled string number).
https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/200605042-Video-GP6-editing-Lyrics-panel

This solution is a little tedious... but it gets the job done (sort of).

Hopefully this capability will be added to GP7. We'll see.

Good luck!